# use hash tag in end of form url?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i want to submit something like this

```
<form action="submit#myresults">
```

I have read here:

https://laravel.io/forum/02-07-2014-how-to-append-hashtag-to-end-of-url-with-redirect

so this won't work:

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'my_fooroute']) !!}
```

what is the cleanest way?

Comment: You cannot use `#` directly on your routes. But you can encode hash to `%23` and use in that way.

so your url will be like `<form action="submit%23myresults">`  I guess it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be the cleanest form:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('my_fooroute') . '#bar'] !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Route::get('/blog#{hash_tag?}', 'Controller@Method')->name('test');
```

Then, you open form like:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['test', 'hash_you_want']]) !!}
```

Or, URL like:

```
<a href="{{ url()->route('test', 'hash_you_want') }}">My Link</a>
```